# How to fix elif expected expression error in python

Tags: python, if-statement, time, pywin32

```
import win32api,time
while True:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x57)
    if a <0:
     print("w")
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x53)
    elif a <0:
    print('s')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

im super new to python the line `elif a<0` gives me the error ```expected expression`` what do i do to make it work? thanks

Comment: indentation is important in python. if you're new you should probably work through some tutorials that cover the basics.

Comment: `elif` should be `if`, since you assigned a new `a` before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a correct indentation in your code when you use `if` and `while` structures, because that will determine the instructions that execute in a certain moment:

```
import win32api, time

while True:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x57)
    if a < 0:
        print("w")
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x53)
    if a < 0:
        print('s')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```